# Image not loaded properly in uiimageView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

Please check attached imageImage not loaded properly in `UIImageView`.

[image]

```
 profileCell.currentMsgView.userPicImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.mediaPath]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) { }];
```

Comment: Where is the code ??? how will ever understand what is happenning ???

Comment: Pls add the code...

Comment: You should post the code, so that we can help you.

Comment: [profileCell.currentMsgView.userPicImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.mediaPath]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                
            }];

Comment: I just load the image from cache and load the image path from document directory

Comment: You should post your code in answer. Right now i have done that but it is for your kind information

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting content mode like,

```
    profileCell.currentMsgView.userPicImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

And make sure that you have set proper constraints. If you have imageview of cell's size then your constraints should be like : `top,leading,trailing,bottom`

This may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple demo app for just learning :-**

*ViewController.h code is here :-*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageOutput;
- (IBAction)btnOutput:(id)sender;

@end
```

*ViewController.m code is here :-*

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnOutput:(id)sender {
    NSString *picUrl = @"http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-9.jpg";
    NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:picUrl];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:theUrl];
    _imageOutput.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
@end
```

Replace whole code of info.plist with the following because without that you will not be able access "http site" because apple will block http site for security reason(for that right click on info.plist and open as source) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```